# JQuery ajax post parameters null in controller

Tags: .net, ajax, post, controller

I have an ajax POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/EmmaWeb/SaveFavourite", //window.location.pathname + "?handler=favourite", //"/it/Umbria/vocabolo-menicaglie-6?handler=favourite",
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', $form).val() },
    //contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8",
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    //dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ isFavourite: $inputIsFavourite.val().toLowerCase(), propertyUnitSlug: $PropertyUnitSlug.val() }),
    cache: false
}).done(function (resp) {
    console.log("done", resp);
});
```

**My controller**:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class EmmaWebController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync(bool isFavourite, string propertyUnitSlug)
    {
        // DO Something

        return new JsonResult(new
        {
            // Something
        });
    }
}
```

I reach my action in controller, but the parameters are always null. I tried adding [FromBody] but i get 415 error

Comment: Please leave a post that describes what have you done to solve your problem. Please do not edit the question with this information. You can mark your own post as the answer, so please use the standard way to close this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved removing [ApiController] attribute from the Controller, and this is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/EmmaWeb/SaveFavourite", //window.location.pathname + "?handler=favourite", //"/it/Umbria/vocabolo-menicaglie-6?handler=favourite",
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', $form).val() },
    //contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8",
    //dataType: "json",
    //contentType: 'application/json',        
    //dataType: "json",
    data: { "isFavourite": $inputIsFavourite.val(), "propertyUnitSlug": $PropertyUnitSlug.val() },
    cache: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FromBodyAttribute` can be used only once, because it uses the entire request body.

There are several workarounds how you can solve this problem:

#### Using a wrapper `class`

```cs
public class SaveFavouriteRequest 
{
   public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
   public string PropertyUnitSlug { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync([FromBody]SaveFavouriteRequest requestData)
{
   var x = requestData.IsFavourite;
}
```

#### Using `JObject`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync([FromBody]JObject requestData)
{
   var x = requestData["isFavourite"].ToObject<bool>();
}
```

#### Using `dynamic`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync([FromBody]dynamic requestData)
{
   var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(requestData.isFavourite.ToString());
}
```

(`.ToLower()` might be required on `ToString()`)

---

### Alternatives without `FromBody`

#### Using `JObject.Parse` and `StreamReader` on `Request.Body`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync()
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
    var requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var requestData = JObject.Parse(requestBody);
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(requestData["isFavourite"].ToString().ToLower());
}
```

#### Using `JObject.LoadAsync` and `JsonTextReader` on `Request.Body`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFavouriteAsync()
{
    using var reader = new HttpRequestStreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
    using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
    var requestData = await JObject.LoadAsync(jsonReader);
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(requestData["isFavourite"].ToString().ToLower());
}
```

Comment: I tried all your solutions, but is not working

Comment: Could you please elaborate *not working*?

Comment: parameters are always null. For example with the warpper class the model is not null, but the value of properties are null

Comment: @zOwN Are you using Newtonsoft Json.NET , right?