# Unpacking a JSON post model to action parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I am tasked with upgrading a large Framework ASP.NET MVC application to .NET 5. Most of the work is done, but I'm running into an issue with HTTP POST calls from the frontend with JSON objects.

Most of these POST calls have a JSON body like this:

```
{
   "param1" : "hello",
   "param2" : "world",
   "param3" : 123
}
```

Its corresponding controller action would look like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(string param1, string param2, int param3)
{
    //Do save stuff
}
```

This doesn't work in ASP.NET Core. The parameters stay empty. I did find one solution, which is to encapsulate these parameters in a model object and use that as the only parameter with a [FromBody] attribute. However, this application has hundreds of actions with all kinds of parameters and I'm really not looking forward to having to write models for all of these.

So, I'm looking for a way to tell ASP.NET to treat the properties of these JSON objects as parameters for the corresponding action. I've googled around a bit, but couldn't find anything useful. Is there any way to do this, or am I stuck with having to write models for every single action?

Comment: I've just posted today [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454318/13268855) where I have listed the different options how you can workaround the limitation of `FromBodyAttribute`. Please check that.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks, but all of these require me to modify every single action, which is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that what you are looking for is viable without extra code. If you don't want to modify the existing code then you can create a facade method for each endpoint. They would receive the parameters (either via `JObject`, `dynamic`, `FromDataCollection`, whatever)  parse them and then they should call the related counterpart.

Comment: A piece of custom routing/binding middleware could do this. Writing such middleware has a learning curve, though, and there appear to be no serious samples in the docs dealing with binding specifically (or indeed most non-trivial middleware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `ValueProvider` for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public async Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        string contentType = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentType].FirstOrDefault();

        bool isJson = contentType == null
            ? false
            : contentType.StartsWith(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        if (isJson)
        {
            context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1024, true))
            {
                string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(body);
                context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // rewind

                var valueProvider = new JsonValueProvider(values);
                context.ValueProviders.Add(valueProvider);
            }
        }
    }
}

//todo: implement better logic for nested objects
public class JsonValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _values;

    public JsonValueProvider(Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        _values = new Dictionary<string, object>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix) => _values.ContainsKey(prefix); 

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        return _values.TryGetValue(key, out object value)
            ? new ValueProviderResult(Convert.ToString(value))
            : ValueProviderResult.None;
    }
}
```

Register `JsonValueProviderFactory` in `Startup.cs`

```
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
        //...
    });
```

**Notes**

This implementation supports only plain values and not complex objects, and requires some testing. If you are binding complex object as action parameter do **not** forget to specify `FromBody` attribute so default model binding takes place and this value provider doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine flexed his Google-fu and eventually found [this library](https://github.com/egorpavlikhin/JsonParametersModelBinder), which is exactly what I needed.